# Output text if there is no SKU in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce site. Some products have SKU and others don't. I found the code below online and it helps me with displaying the text when visitors arrive at my single product page.

Once there, they can select from the drop-down menus to see specific info, including SKU, for each product variation.

Some of my products don't have SKU.  How can I modify the code to display text (in the same place that SKU would have displayed) like "Please call us for part number".

```
<div class="product_meta">

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>

<?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>
    <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'VSI Part Number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'Choose option(s) to display part number.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

<?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how to add custom fields after SKU in single product page.

```
/**
     * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
 */
```

The "in Stock" or "SKU" data is displayed by woocommerce_template_single_meta which have a priority of 40. Now you need to display your customs fields values just after. Then you can chose a priority of 45 for that purpose

> Here is the code that is going to output your custom fields values in
>   product pages under "SKU":

```
///////////////////////////////
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woo_display_custom_general_fields_values', 45);
    function woo_display_custom_general_fields_values() {
        global $product;

    echo '<span class="sku_wrapper">'. esc_html_e( 'VSI Part Number:', 'woocommerce' ); . '<span class="sku">'. ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'Choose option(s) to display part number.', 'woocommerce' ); .'</span></span>';
}
//////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have some variable products that don't have SKUs.  In that case, when visitors select from the dropdowns to get to those variable products, they will see the message "Please call us for part number" instead of "Choose option(s) to display part number." because they already chose the options from the dropdowns.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes could you please provide?